# sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield: No such file or directory

Tags: security, linux-kernel, sysctl

Enable ExecShield protection - ExecShield is security Linux kernel patch to avoid worms and other problems.

After Adding to

```
/etc/sysctl 
kernel.exec-shield = 1
```

Getting this error sysctl: cannot `stat /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield: No such file or directory`

Output :

```
root@ashishk:/home/ashish/MyScripts# sysctl -p

sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield: No such file or directory

kernel.randomize_va_space = 1

net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1

net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048

net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 5

net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1

net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1

net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Can i know what is wrong ?

Comment: please can you provide what distribution you are using? maybe you are using a new distribution, exec-shield is present in redhat 5 and I don't this problem, but maybe is deprecated in the newers distro.

Comment: ashish@ashishk:~$ sudo lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: I think exec-shield was redhat related, anyway i'm using centos 7 and exec-shield doesn't exist no more, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_Shield

Comment: @c4f4t0r why don't you write your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c4f4t0r already provided an answer to the immediate question in the comments, but it is not entirely accurate.

exec-shield continues to exist; what actually was removed was the option to disable it through the sysctl setting

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/974563 (link requires a RedHat Subscription. Not providing the exact cite from that link due to copyright concerns).